# usage of reselect in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

i have set of components those use central store(i.e. redux store) via container component. these components are tend to be flat simple and reside within HOC component. HOC component utilizes **react-redux connect**.

```
class HOComponent extends Component {
   const { data1, data2 } = this.props;
   render() {
      <Component1 data={data1} />
      <Component2 data={data2} />
   }
}
const selector = (state) => ({
    data1 = selectors.data1(state),
    data2 = selectors.data2(state),
    other = selectors.other(state)
});
```

above is the selector for child component **Component1** **Component2** respectively.

Below how is the selectors look like which utilizes **reselect**.

```
const alldata = (state) => 
    state.alldata;

 export other = (state) =>
     state.other;

 export data1 = createSelector(
 [alldata], 
 (alldata) => {
    //lets assume
    return alldata.filter(d => d.criteria === data1.criteria);
  })

 export data2 = createSelector(
 [alldata], 
 (alldata) => {
    //lets assume
    return alldata.filter(d => d.criteria === data2.criteria);
  })
```

the question is this right usage of the **reselect** i noticed this is ineffective, since if my HOC **other** selctor triggered **Component1** **Component2** also being rerendered anyway. should i be checking each data flow within **shouldComponentUpdate** method. i thought **reselect** usage will battle with this issue in first place. did i misunderstand it. is it only prevents recalculation part?

this is continuation of my earlier post 
[prevent selectors of child components being triggerred in redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091011/prevent-selectors-of-child-components-being-triggerred-in-redux)

Comment: "is it only prevents recalculation part?". yes.